# What is wrong with this React conditional rendering expression?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I had the below Reactjs snippet in our UI, which works fine now.

```
<Select
                    label="Send To"
                    labelId="send-to-label"
                    required
                    error={state.submitted && !state.sendTo}
                    fullWidth
                    placeholder="Select contact"
                    id="send-to"
                    value={state.sendTo ? state.sendTo.contactId : ''}
                    onChange={selectSendToChanged}
                    MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: 'contactMenuList' } }}
                >
                    {state.sendToContacts.map((contact: Contact) => (
                        <MenuItem key={contact.contactId} value={contact.contactId}>
                            {contact.name} - {contact.phone}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
```

I don't want the `contact.phone` field to be shown when it is an empty string.

I tried implementing condition rendering like this:

```
<Select
                    label="Send To"
                    labelId="send-to-label"
                    required
                    error={state.submitted && !state.sendTo}
                    fullWidth
                    placeholder="Select contact"
                    id="send-to"
                    value={state.sendTo ? state.sendTo.contactId : ''}
                    onChange={selectSendToChanged}
                    MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: 'contactMenuList' } }}
                >
                    {state.sendToContacts.map((contact: Contact) => (
                        <MenuItem key={contact.contactId} value={contact.contactId}>
                            {contact.contactId != 'other' 
                                ? {contact.name} - {contact.phone}
                                : {contact.name}
                            }
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
```

but it gives "*The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.*" error on `contact.phone` field. I also tried the below snippet (the same as above but without curly brackets) but it dumps the entire JS line as a string on the UI.

```
<Select
                    label="Send To"
                    labelId="send-to-label"
                    required
                    error={state.submitted && !state.sendTo}
                    fullWidth
                    placeholder="Select contact"
                    id="send-to"
                    value={state.sendTo ? state.sendTo.contactId : ''}
                    onChange={selectSendToChanged}
                    MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: 'contactMenuList' } }}
                >
                    {state.sendToContacts.map((contact: Contact) => (
                        <MenuItem key={contact.contactId} value={contact.contactId}>
                            contact.contactId != 'other' 
                                ? {contact.name} - {contact.phone}
                                : {contact.name}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `MenuItem` in your conditional rendering block looks incorrect. You might want to change it to the following:

```
<MenuItem key={contact.contactId} value={contact.contactId}>
  {contact.contactId != 'other' 
    ? `${contact.name} - ${contact.phone}`
    : contact.name}
</MenuItem>
```

This is because anything inside curly braces is interpreted as a JS expression, so your conditional rendering version was equivalent to, for example, `"John" - ""` or `"John" - "555-555-5555"`. Wrapping the string to be rendered in a template string avoids trying to evaluate this as an expression.

Comment: It didn't work. I see the string `contact.contactId != 'other' ? '$TestName - 041233': TestName` in my menu option on the page.

Comment: It is very likely that you have not wrapped it in curly braces. Try copy pasting this snippet exactly how it is.